# slice_mut for &mut [T]

Tags: rust

Why [MutableSlice::slice_mut](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/trait.MutableSlice.html#tymethod.slice_mut) is not implemented for &mut [T]?

Tested on rustc 0.12.0-nightly (b2d4eb186 2014-10-02 15:57:19 +0000):

```
fn sort<T>(v: &mut [T]){
    let (l, r) = v.split_at_mut(2); // Ok
    let len = v.slice_mut(1u, 3u).len(); // error: type `&mut [T]` does not implement any method in scope named `slice_mut`
}

#[test]
fn it_works() {
    let mut v = [1i, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    sort(v);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That method [had been removed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/17620), but [the change has since been rolled back](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/17715). The second line of your `sort` function [compiles right now](http://is.gd/yCOdYS).